# What is the proper solution when using find with a guaranteed value?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, proof-of-correctness

In Haskell, `find` is designed to evaluate as a Maybe, because when scanning a list for an element matching a predicate, it could fail. However, consider the following:

```
factorize n | isPrime n = [n]
            | otherwise = m : factorize (n `div` m)
            where m = find ((==0) . (n `mod`)) [2..]
```

`find` here will clearly find a value in every case, assuming we’re only hitting integers greater than 2. If a number is not prime, then it has a factor somewhere in the infinite list [2..]. But of course, Haskell doesn’t know that, and will still complain that a Maybe is being used. What is the solution here?

1. Use `fromMaybe` with some dummy default value to extract the inner value. The default value will never be used.
2. Use something like `head . dropWhile` to act as a kind of “unsafe find”.
3. Bubble the Maybes all the way up and have the factors returned as a list of Maybes.
4. Some way to tell Haskell “look, the math checks out, this is safe, just trust me.”

1 and 2 are smelly, 3 is cumbersome and adds failure state to a function it shouldn’t exist in, and I don’t know whether 4 exists. What is the best solution here?

Edit: The above list of options is incomplete without mentioning `fromJust`, which takes a `Just` and returns the value inside it, and throws an error when given a `Nothing`. I think that's clearly the short answer to my question, and I wasn't aware of its existence until I read the answers and comments here. However, there are still good points made about safety and fail state in general in the answers below.

Comment: Another option is `fromJust`, which doesn't require a dummy default value

Comment: This is one of those cases where `fromJust` is justified. Crashing is better than silently returning a wrong dummy result, which would lead to debugging nightmares.

Comment: `find` is inefficient, because you are repeatedly scanning the same (increasingly long) prefix of `[2..]` to find the next prime that divides `n`. Consider generating an infinite list of primes first, and walking through that list as you build up the list of factors.

Comment: (Sorry, not `find` itself, but the way you are using it here.)

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't aware of `fromJust`'s existence, and that's clearly the short answer to my question. The discussion about safety and fail states is still helpful to my understanding of the fundamentals, though, so I'm glad I asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution 1 would work, but is unidiomatic.

Solution 2/4 would be to use `fromJust` or pattern matching:

```
factorize n | isPrime n = [n]
            | otherwise = m : factorize (n div m)
            where m = fromJust $ find ((==0) . (n `mod`)) [2..] -- trust me, if a number is not prime, then it has a factor somewhere
```

```
factorize n | isPrime n = [n]
            | otherwise = m : factorize (n div m)
            where (Just m) = find ((==0) . (n `mod`)) [2..] -- trust me, if a number is not prime, then it has a factor somewhere
```

The comment is kinda important to point out to the reader that this is safe and will never cause an exception. There's no way to tell Haskell though, it will still generate code to throw an exception should a `Nothing` occur.

You'll need to prove its correctness yourself. You may notice that it's actually wrong - try with `factorize 1`!

> What is the best solution here?

Don't duplicate the work in the first place. `isPrime` will also try to find a factor, then return `False` if it found one and return `True` if it didn't. Instead of trying to find the factor again in the case where `isPrime n` returned `False`, use the factor from the search you just did!

```
-- TODO: prove that the returned factor is actually prime
-- TODO: optimise by using [2..(floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n)]
findPrimeFactor :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
findPrimeFactor n = find ((==0) . (n `mod`)) [2..n-1]

factorize 1 = []
factorize n = case findPrimeFactor n of
                Nothing -> [n]
                Just m  -> m : factorize (n div m)

isPrime 1 = False
isPrime n = case findPrimeFactor n of
              Nothing -> True
              Just _  -> False
```

or alternatively

```
-- TODO: prove that the returned number is actually prime
findPrimeFactor :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
findPrimeFactor n = find ((==0) . (n `mod`)) [2..n]
--                                               ^ note the difference

factorize n = case findPrimeFactor n of
                Nothing -> []
                Just m  -> m : factorize (n div m)

isPrime n = (Just n) == findPrimeFactor n
```

Comment: Well, you could avoid the comment by putting `fromJustTrustMeItWontFail = fromJust` in the `where` :D

Comment: @Enlico A use of `fromJust` always implies "Trust me, it won't fail". The point of the comment is to give the human reader a reason to trust you.

Comment: I was implyint that a `fromJust` could be a mistake, whereas using a synonym like `fromJustTrustMeItWontFail` better conveys that "I've truly spent some time to understand it's right thing to do (whatever the reason is)".

Comment: @Enlico Still worse than just putting the actual reason *why* (you think) it won't fail in a comment, which should enable anyone to verify the reasoning instead of having to trust the author. `fromJustTrustMeItWontFail` could still be a mistake. `fromJust` isn't used lightly either, the author would (should?) already have spent some time thinking on why `fromJust` is the right thing to do, like with any code.

Comment: You’ll thank yourself later if you write `fromMaybe (error "⟨explanation⟩") mx` instead of `fromJust mx  -- ⟨explanation⟩`. With the former, you’ll get an error message if it fails. With the latter, you need `HasCallStack` or `+RTS -xc` to get more info than `*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing`. Although `HasCallStack` isn’t a bad idea either way.

Comment: "it's actually wrong - try with `factorize 1`" - I addressed this in the question. I wanted to keep the code concise for SO purposes, but when I actually write this function I pattern match on n < 2 to handle invalid input. In any case, this is a complete and very helpful answer, thank you!

Comment: @JonPurdy That still seems clunky in cases where you *know* it will never fail. Maybe it's technically safer, but one of the things that's nice about pure functions is that you can *prove* they will never fail. Is this standard Haskell practice, or would most devs just use `fromJust`?

Comment: @Enlico The point of the comment is also to tell a future editor of the code what they need to consider as they edit the code in order to *keep* the "trust me it won't fail" promise reliable. `fromJustTrustMeItWontFail` doesn't communicate any more than `fromJust`; the reader still has to deduce from the code what keeps it from failing. You could actually replace the comment by using `fromJustIfANumberIsn'tPrimeItHasAFactor = fromJust`, but it's really irrelevant whether it's syntactically a comment or you shoehorn it into an internal name; the point is to **communicate** something.

Comment: @scatter `fromJust` is often considered a code smell; using an explicit error message is slightly less smelly, so yes, it's pretty standard practice. When you can really **prove** it can't fail (as opposed to "this external service always returns data with this key, so I don't need to handle its absence") then it really doesn't matter very much, so go ahead and use whichever feels better. I've certainly used both forms. But I would always feel the desire to restructure the algorithm to avoid **needing** to prove it can't fail, just to avoid the smell.

Answer (score 7):

Using `fromMaybe` (or `fromJust`) (option 1) is a typical way to "tell Haskell 'just trust me'" (option 4).

What is smelly is precisely having to say "just trust me", because programmers are untrustworthy. Users of strongly typed languages prefer encoding invariants in the type system so they can be enforced automatically. However arithmetic is a notorious aspect of programming that mainstream type systems are not yet well-equipped to handle, so you do have to resort to throwing errors in unreachable cases. Dependent/refinement types (cf. Liquid Haskell) are a technology that would let you reason about arithmetic within a language's type system.